# Allow specific users from outside my intranet to access website

Tags: apache, intranet, wan

I have an intranet website setup at my house. I'm running under XAMPP. Everything works fine. I'd like to give access to specific users in order for them to test the website (private testing) instead of making it available to the internet. Specifically, I want specific users to have private access to my intranet website and others would be denied access to that site.

I already configured port forwarding on my router. What would be the extra steps I'd need to take?

Answer (score 0):

if the testers have static IPs you can configure ACLs on your router or even on your Server.

if there are dynamic IPs you can create openVPN to your tester's site and use DDNS as remote peer's IP.

hope that helps!